# values added between dates in stackplot python

Tags: python

I have data being put into a stackplot with counts on the y axis and dates on the x axis. there are gaps in the dates (ie I have data for every day from 4/22/1995 to 4/27/1995 but then nothing until 5/5/1995). the plot seems to be adding data between these dates but I am unsure why.

a copy of the data frame which the plot calls from:

```
1997-02-16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,99,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,99
1997-02-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,149,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,149
1997-02-13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104
1997-02-12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,114
1997-02-11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,138,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,138
1997-02-10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,98,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,98
1997-02-09,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,135,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,135
1997-02-08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,148,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,148
1997-02-07,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,157,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,157
1997-02-06,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,156,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,156
1997-02-05,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,138,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,138
1997-02-04,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,126,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,126
1997-02-03,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,87,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,87
1997-02-02,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,67,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,67
1995-10-25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,77
1995-10-24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46
1995-10-22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,69,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,69
1995-10-21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,124,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,124
1995-10-20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,126,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,126
1995-10-19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,61,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,61
1995-10-18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29
1995-10-17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9
1995-10-16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,78,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,78
1995-10-15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104
1995-10-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,112,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,112
1995-10-13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,106,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,106
1995-10-12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,107,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,107
1995-10-11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104
1995-10-10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22
1995-07-09,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58
1995-07-08,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,66,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,66
1995-07-07,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29
1995-07-06,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45
1995-07-05,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,51,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,51
1995-07-04,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88
1995-07-03,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,86,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,86
1995-07-02,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,95,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,95
1995-07-01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,78,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,78
1995-06-30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,88
1995-06-29,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,110,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,110
1995-06-28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,103,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,103
1995-06-27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,83,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,83
1995-06-26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,93
1995-06-25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,60,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,60
1995-06-23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,104
1995-06-22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,90
1995-06-21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,107,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,107
1995-06-20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,54
1995-06-19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30
1995-05-05,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50
1995-04-27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,55,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,55
1995-04-26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22
1995-04-25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,77
1995-04-24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,102,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,102
1995-04-23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,56,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,56
1995-04-22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,66,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,66
```

my code is as follows

```
ax1.stackplot(df[0],df[8])
```

the plot I get is:

[image: stack plot i get with data added between date of data]

I would have expected to get:

[image: same data plotted in excel]

Comment: what do u expect?

Answer (score 0):

To get the plot that you are looking for (in second picture), you should not be using `stackplot`. You can read about the kind of graphs that are created using stackplot [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stackplot_demo.html). You should use a simple `bar` plot and that will give you the required plot as shown in the second graph.

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', header = None)
df[0]=pd.to_datetime(df[0])
plt.bar(df[0],df[8])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Comment: looking at the uses for stackplots actually confirms that it is correct for what I want. I had not mentioned that this is only one of many (about 21) data sets I would like to display because this is the first data set I have come across with large periods of time between non 0 count days and that displays in what seems to me an odd manor. that being said the bar chart i tried producing also does not match your output.